# Can or should a registered gen_fsm tell its own supervisor to remove itself?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am using a `supervisor` to spawn and monitor `gen_fsm`s. Under certain circumstances, `gen_fsm` will be shutdown. Later on, the `supervisor` will spawn new `gen_fsm` under the same `id` as previously applied.

Specifically speaking, my `gen_fsm` are supervised chatbots. The same user should talk to the same chatbot. When user no longer communicates to the bot, the bot shuts down. This is where I want the bot to be unregistered from its supervisor but don't know which party should initiate `supervisor:delete_child/2` and when.

Should I call during the `terminate/3` of `gen_fsm`? Please help.

## UPDATE

Here's my repo https://github.com/khanhhua/erlbot

Answer (score 2):

This is what `transient` restart in child specification is for:

> [A transient child process is restarted only if it terminates abnormally, that is, with an exit reason other than `normal`, `shutdown`, or `{shutdown,Term}`.](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html)

Comment: In fact I do use `transient`. But that is not the issue. Here's my repo https://github.com/khanhhua/erlbot

Comment: At least in `erlbot_bot` I don't see anywhere where you stop the bot with a normal reason to benefit from `transient`.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. It's in branch feat/start-bot. Here https://github.com/khanhhua/erlbot/blob/feat/start-bot/src/erlbot_bot.erl

Comment: When process terminates it automatically unregisters.

Comment: just returning from gen_fsm callback {stop, normal, State} should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Alexey and @Vladimir for your inputs. I have solved the issue.

The key to my issue is that supervisor `erlbot_sup` still keep a list of child specs, which means `Children = [DeadChildSpec]`

```
get_bot(Username) ->
  Children = supervisor:which_children({global, ?SERVER}),
  %% {Name, Pid, ChildType, Mods}
  case lists:keyfind(Username, 1, Children) of
    {Name, BotPid, _ChildType, _Mods} ->
      if
        BotPid =:= undefined ->
          supervisor:delete_child({global, ?SERVER}, Name),
          {error, deadbot};
        true -> {ok, BotPid}
      end;
    false -> {error, not_found}
  end.
```

Hence I have to check whether `DeadChildSpec`'s `Pid` is `undefined` to determine such `ChildSpec` is subject to removal during `create_bot`.

```
create_bot(Username) ->
  %% Bots are "singletons"
  Result = case get_bot(Username) of
    {error, Error} when (Error =:= not_found) or (Error =:= deadbot) ->
      if
        Error =:= deadbot -> io:format("Bot ~p was a deadbot~n", [Username]);
        true -> true
      end,

      MFA = {erlbot_bot,start_link,[Username]},
      supervisor:start_child({global, ?SERVER},
        #{id => Username,
          start => MFA,
          restart => transient,
          type => worker
        });

    {ok, BotPid} -> {ok, BotPid}
  end,

  io:format("Result: ~p~n", [Result]),

  Result.
```

So - the answer to my question is:

- Supervised `gen_fsm` must be started with `transient` `restart_type` (Thank you, Alexey, for affirming)
- Supervised `gen_fsm` must terminate itself with `{stop, shutdown}` or `{stop, normal}` (Thank you, Vladimir, for affirming)
- Supervisor should do the cleanup prior to subsequent `gen_fsm` to guarantee these "singletons".
- `gen_fsm:terminate/3` should not involve `supervisor:delete_child` because such would result in `{error, running}`.

Comment: is "Bot ~p was a deadbot~n" ever printed in your testing?

Comment: @LynHeadley Yes! After the `{stop, normal}` or `{stop, shutdown}` transition.